# Fire many intents form many places to a single activity (with one instance)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, singleton

I want to have a single activity but from many places intents are fired also those intents sometimes can be called like two times in 10 seconds...

the point is I want to have only a single activity, and every time when a new intent comes I want just to refresh the gui state of the activity

how can I do this ?

I put android:launchMode="singleTask" and singleinstance but the problem is that onNewIntent is not called at all...

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    refreshGuiState();
}
```

EDIT

```
   <activity android:name="MyActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleTask" 

    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
    </activity>

  Intent i=new Intent(MyApp.myContext, MyActivity.class);
            MyApp.myContext.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Post your manifest. Also, where are these Intents coming from? From within this task? From many other tasks? From background services?

Comment: from many tasks, how my definition for the activity should look like in the manifest ?, I do not have code that works , I need one so if you can post something, thanks

Comment: Are multiple instances of your activity being created? Add logging to check this. Also, post the code that you use to fire the Intents

Comment: @David Wasser if you have some solution please give me a spinets what should I do to make it work, if you do not know how to fix this then do not spam, I do not have working code, everything I have are some snippets found on net, but I do not have the the right thing that is why I wrote here to find the source code that will resolve my describer problem

Comment: If I understand you right, you need to send some asynchronous messages into your running activity.  Then why not use BroadcastReceiver in your activity and send broadcasts to them?

Comment: I need to receive intents to my current visible activity, and to update this visible activity according the data that is cried in the intents. If have broadcast receiver won't fix anything I still need to update the visible activity after every intent...

Comment: I'm sorry you think my questions are spam :-( I'm trying to understand your problem and to see what you've done in order to give you a useful answer. There are at least 5 different ways to do what you want to do, depending on the rest of your requirements. StackOverflow isn't a community of programmers that provide free code on demand.

Comment: @DavidWasser I am sorry if you are somehow insulted I didn't meant to do that, but I told you that I do not have any working code, all I have is provided in the question, you do not have to give me code to solve my problem it is enough to give me clear guide lines, for example use android:launchMode ..., but everything I tried so far didn't work

Comment: launchMode have probably nothing to do with receiving intents. What are *exactly* the intents you're trying to listen to? You probably need to reply to the first question of @David Wasser in order for us to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:taskAffinity=""` to the manifest definition for `MyActivity`

Even though you've specified `launchMode="singleTask"` for this activity, if you don't explicitly specify `taskAffinity` you won't end up with a separate task.